# How to send a session cookie with rails devise and iOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, curl, devise

Im trying authorize in server with

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user":   {"email":"EgorkZe@gmail.com","password":"1234"}}'  http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in
```

it's give me response

```
session = 654a8f9be39839e0eac5b06c7224d671;
success = 1;
user =     {
    "authentication_token" = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "2014-04-10T08:54:28.813Z";
    email = "egorkze@gmail.com";
    id = 1;
    "server_id" = "<null>";
    "updated_at" = "2014-04-11T07:27:23.580Z";
};
```

and this is ruby sessions_controller.rb

```
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create

    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "sessions#failure")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    respond_to do | format |
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :user => resource ,:session => session['session_id']}, :status => 200 }
    end

  end

  def failure
    respond_to do | format |
      format.json { render :status => 401, :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]} }
    end

  end  
end
```

How can i send session cookie and how can i keep session. When i send to rails with curl different get request it's give me ""Login failed.""

Answer (score 0):

By default cUrl doesn't save cookies. You can add `--cookie-jar <filename>` to have it save the cookies to a file on your disk. You can also pass the session id you have a as a cookie manually:

```
-b "session=654a8f9be39839e0eac5b06c7224d671"
```

I'm not sure what this has to do with iOS? `nsHTTP` should handle cookies properly (though it does not play nice with `protect_from_forgery`.